# preg_match_all email 'To' value empty

Tags: php, email, preg-match-all

I have an email saved in a file

```
Date: Wed, 9 Apr 2014 14:33:11 +0000
Return-Path: x.com
To: personsEamilAddress@email.com
From: x
Subject: Hello world
Message-ID: <x>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.1 (phpmailer.sourceforge.net)
Sender: senderEmail@mail.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
X-SES-Outgoing: 2014.04.09-54.240.8.56
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

I'm trying to work out who the email was sent to? ie **personsEamilAddress@email.com**

I've tried

```
preg_match_all('/To: (.*?)/', $subject, $result, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($result);
```

But the array that is printed out doesn't contain the value of the email address.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => To: 
            [1] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => To: 
            [1] => 
        )

)
```

Comment: This worked in my test: `%\To\: (.*)%`

Comment: try as `"/To:(.*)/im"`

Comment: You can use the regex101 tool here: http://regex101.com/

Comment: Thanks both. Works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the `?` in your search group.

Also, the `s` modifier at the end let's you select everything with the `.` including line breaks and whitespaces.

The Solution therefore would be:

```
%^To: (.*)%m
```

The `m` Modifier causes `^` and `$` to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)

Comment: `:` doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: What regex tool do you use? (just curious)

Comment: Just an online tool http://regex101.com/
But you where right. I missinterpreted the highlighting.

Comment: I'd just use `^To: (.*)` with `m` modifier.

Comment: @AmalMurali very good. Works like a charm and is shorter. But doesn't this only work if by default the regex tool is on lazy rather than greedy? Othjerwise we'd need a $ at the end right?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's greedy because it only consume until the end of **that particular line**. (unless you enable `s` modifier)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with:

```
preg_match_all('/To: (.*)?/', $subject, $result, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($result);
```

It should return:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => To: personsEmailAddress@email.com
        [1] => personsEmailAddress@email.com
    )
)
```